# How to convert NFA with null moves to NFA without null moves?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, finite-automata

I am converting NFA **with $\varepsilon$-moves**  to the NFA **without**  $\varepsilon$-null moves. I understand that if, there is a $\varepsilon$-move between, $q_i$ and $q_j$, then all edges from $q_j$ have to be repeated from $q_i$. And if the $q_j$ is a final state, then $q_i$ will also be a final state.

But, if $q_j$ does not contain any transition, i.e., there are no edges starting from $q_j$, then what has to be done?

Answer (score 2):

If $q_j$ is a final state, you already said you would make $q_i$ into a final state. If there's no transitions from $q_j$ to another state in the FSM, then you are staying there forever- either as an accepting state or as a trap state. Either way, staying in $q_i$ is the same as staying in $q_j$ if you can't go anywhere from $q_j$.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, you do exactly as you said. If $q_j$ does not contain any transition you don't have anything to do so you do nothing more than removing $q_j$ and updating $q_i$ as final if $q_j$ is final.